# The value of the limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

The value of the limit

$$ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum _{j=n} ^{4n}  {4n \choose j} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^j \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{4n-j} $$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X_n\sim\mathrm{Bin}\Big(4n,\frac14\Big)$, then the given sum is $P(X_n\geq n)$. Now $\Bbb{E}(X_n)=4n\cdot\frac14=n$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X_n)=4n\cdot\frac14\cdot\frac34=\frac{3n}4$. Now by Central Limit Theorem,
$$\frac{X_n-n}{\sqrt{3n/4}}\xrightarrow{d} Z$$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. So $$P(X_n\geq n)=P\Big(\frac{X_n-n}{\sqrt{3n/4}}\ge0\Big)\to P(Z\ge0)=\frac12$$